non-std C++ exception in react native expo app - how do i resolve this?
I keep getting this error : 'non-std C++ exception'
This is my tailwind.config file content, for reference my file structure is
packages
|-pages
| |-homescreen
| | |-index.js
| | |-ui
| | | |-index.js
| | | |-HomeScreen.js
| | |-assets
| | | |-index.js
| |-login
| | |-index.js // etc
content: [
    "./*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", 
    "./pages/**/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],


here is my babel config:
// babel.config.js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: [
      ["babel-preset-expo", { jsxImportSource: "nativewind" }],
      "nativewind/babel",
      ["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: 'current' } }],
      ["@babel/preset-react", { runtime: "automatic" }]
    ],
    plugins: [
      // Required for expo-router
      "react-native-reanimated/plugin",
      "@babel/transform-react-jsx-source",
    ]
  };
};


I have tried clearing cache and removing and re installing npm - this hasn't helped and i'm still seeing the error.
If anyone has any ideas on how to solve this i would be grateful!
